# Render TYPO3 Fluid partial from another extension

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I want to render a section in a partial from another extension.
My setup is TYPO3 7.6.14 with fluid powered TYPO3 extensions including VHS.

As far as i know it is not possible with the fluid ViewHelper [f:render](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/RenderViewHelper.html). Here you only have the arguments "partial" and "section".
I found one solution using the VHS ViewHelper [v:render.template](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Render/TemplateViewHelper.html). 
The solution is explained here: https://www.wapplersystems.de/blog/typo3-fluid-render-partial-from-another-extension/

But with this ViewHelper I can only set the path to the partial, but not to the section.

Answer (score 20):

Fluid supports a lookup chain for partials, templates and layouts. You can specify multiple directories in your extension and fluid will look in all of them (beginning at the highest index) until it finds a matching partial file.

```
plugin.tx_myextension.view {
   partialRootPaths {
      10 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials
      20 = EXT:another_extension/Resources/Private/Partials
   }
}
```

With this configuration fluid will look for every partial in your extension at `another_extension/Resources/Private/Partials` first and render it from there if it is present.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is also my current solution. But it is not very satisfying, because you alway have to check against overriding partials from the current extension. Thats why i was hoping finding another solution, where i you only will Path to one single Partial and not include the whole partial folder.

Comment: @kimomat As the entries this list are looked up in ascending order, how bout you create a folder where only your generalized templates go into and place that on top of the list.